# How to close PopupWindow in OnItemClickListener of GridView, if the GridView is in the PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-popupwindow

I have a GridView A in a PopupWindow A.

And I just want to close the PopupWindow A, if I click one item in the GridView A.

Now It's just like when I open the result Fragment, the PopupWindow A keep stay on the screen.

And the PopupWindow A is also popup from a item in a GridView B.

So I've implement the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`  to the GridView B.

```
GridViewImplement.java:
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long id){

      View popupView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
      final PopupWindow mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 800, 500, true); 

      if(id != 0){

        GridView gridViewA = (GridView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_a_popup);
        GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(activity, list, true);
        gridViewA.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

        GridViewImplement impl =  new GridViewImplement(activity).
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(impl.mOnItemClickListener);

        Button closeButton = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup_close);
                if (closeButton != null) {
                    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mPopupWindow.dismiss();// here is works.
                        }
                    });
                }

      }else{
        mPopupWindow.dismiss();// here not work.

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        activity.replaceFragment(ResultFragment.newInstance(),bundle,R.id.fragment_result);

      }
   }
}
```

**modify code**

```
GridViewImplement.java:

PopupWindow mPopupWindow;

public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long id){

      View popupView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);


      if(id != 0){
        mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 800, 500, true);
        GridView gridViewA = (GridView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_a_popup);
        GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(activity, list, true);
        gridViewA.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

        GridViewImplement impl =  new GridViewImplement(activity).
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(impl.mOnItemClickListener);

        Button closeButton = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup_close);
                if (closeButton != null) {
                    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mPopupWindow.dismiss();// here will warning need key 'final'.
                        }
                    });
                }

      }else{
        mPopupWindow.dismiss();// here not work.

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        activity.replaceFragment(ResultFragment.newInstance(),bundle,R.id.fragment_result);

      }
   }
}
```

**works code got form my friend**

```
GridViewImplement.java:
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long id){

      View popupView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
      final PopupWindow mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 800, 500, true);

      if(id != 0){
        GridView gridViewA = (GridView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_a_popup);
        GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(activity, list, true);
        gridViewA.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

        //GridViewImplement impl =  new GridViewImplement(activity).
        //gridView.setOnItemClickListener(impl.mOnItemClickListener);// here just use a total new implement. 
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        mPopupWindow.dismiss();// works here.
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        activity.replaceFragment(ResultFragment.newInstance(),bundle,R.id.fragment_result);

                    }
                });

        Button closeButton = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup_close);
                if (closeButton != null) {
                    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mPopupWindow.dismiss();// works here
                        }
                    });
                }

      }else{
        //mPopupWindow.dismiss(); // here looks like not needed any more.

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        activity.replaceFragment(ResultFragment.newInstance(),bundle,R.id.fragment_result);

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually you are creating a new object of mPopupWindow in the onItemClick method and you are dismissing the new one.

Comment: @Krish so where should I move the ‘final PopupWindow’ code to. or how do I re-organize these feature.

Comment: Can you make it global variable and if not null dismiss the popover.

Comment: @Krish when I make it to global, it will warning that "can't assign a value to final variable 'mPopupWindow'"

Comment: Why are you using final ?

Comment: @Krish If I remove the 'final' keyword, it will warning that "Variable 'mPopupWindow' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final"

Comment: can you post the modified code.

Comment: @Krish I have got the solution, and thanks again. You point the root cause that I just dismissing not the one I created at the begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an OnClickListener for your GridView and add popupWindow.dismiss() to close the popup. Basically doing something like this:

```
gridView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    popupWindow.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: My implementation is a little complex. Let me include some code.